# Repopulating form fields with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, populate

Hi Sorry I'm newbie in Javascript but I need to know how I can do to repopulate a form field when I have this kind of form :

I tried with this code(part) but it doesn't work,the file name is 'testjavascript.html'

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   
 function updateUsername(){        
     var first = document.getElementById("first").value;              
     document.getElementById("first").value = first;    
  } </script>

</head>
<body>
      <form action="action.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="usename" value="" id="first" >
            <a href="testjavascript.html?auto=1" onclick="updateUsername();" id ="link">Link</a>
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
      </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code equals to: `var a= "a"; var b = a; a = b;` very helpful!

Comment: It looks like you are getting the value of `first` then reassigning it back to that same field? What field are you trying to get the value from and where are you trying to put it?

Comment: I want when I click on the href link the content of the field with name="username" and id="first" remain the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior needs to be on the server side. When you change page, the browser will reload your javascript code and you will lose all references.

Comment: I don't change the page,its the same page testjavascript.html

Comment: But when you click the link, does the whole page refresh?

Comment: @Alex so that's what Valmir is pointing out, that when you click the link, your browser redirects to another page; even if its the exact same page that gets reloaded, the result is that you lose all the context from the previous page. You can't save it through javascript in the way you're doing it; you'd have to either save it in a cookie and load it back up on page reload, or pass it as part of the query string, or as Valmir said, save it server side and re-expose it to the newly rendered page.